# Do the Monk's mantras affect Witch Doctor pets?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

As per the title, do the Monk's mantras affect the Witch Doctor's pets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do.

A number of battle.net threads discuss it, but [this one](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4903521032) takes a serious look at group composition and confirms that the theory is sound.

The standing speculation is that this will be changed as it is a very powerful combination.